# ClosedXML Excel filter rows by values in multiple columns

Tags: c#, excel, windows-7, closedxml

I have a Excel file with several thousand rows and columns up to "BP".
I need to filter all of these rows by specific values in columns C and BP.

I tested the filter functionality in ClosedXML as per the code below.

When I apply a filter to one column all works well and the data is saved in the new file.

When I try to apply two filters, the last one executed is the one that is applied.

I have tried to use the worksheet as a Range/Table, same filtering problem.

I eventually created the "rows" expression, that works, but the 1st row (header) is filtered out.

```
public static void Filter(string source, string newFile)
    {
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(source))
        {
            IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

            int salesFoundCell = worksheet.FirstRow().Cells().First(c => c.Value.ToString() == "Sales Order Description").Address.ColumnNumber;
            int revenueFoundCell = worksheet.FirstRow().Cells().First(c => c.Value.ToString() == "Revenue recognition date").Address.ColumnNumber;

            //worksheet.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter().Column(salesFoundCell).EqualTo("Equipment Sale");
            //worksheet.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter().Column(revenueFoundCell).EqualTo("00.00.0000");             

            //var rows = worksheet.RowsUsed().Where(r => r.CellsUsed().Any(c => c.GetString().Contains("Equipment Sale")) && 
            //                                          r.CellsUsed().Any(c => c.GetString().Contains("00.00.0000")));

           Console.WriteLine(rows.Count());

            //workbook.SaveAs(newFile);             
        }
    }
```

I also tried the method posted on the ClosedXML wiki, where you save the worksheet as a MemoryStream, reapply the filter and then save it to a new file.

This is the short version:

```
public void Create(string filePath)
    {
        var wb = new XLWorkbook();
        IXLWorksheet ws;

        #region Multi Column
        String multiColumn = "Multi Column";
        ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(multiColumn);

        // Add filters
        ws.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter().Column(2).EqualTo(3).Or.GreaterThan(4);
        ws.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter().Column(3).Between("B", "D");

        // Sort the filtered list
        ws.AutoFilter.Sort(3);
        #endregion

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(ms);

            var workbook = new XLWorkbook(ms);

            #region Multi Column 
            workbook.Worksheet(multiColumn).AutoFilter.Column(3).EqualTo("E");
            workbook.Worksheet(multiColumn).AutoFilter.Sort(3, XLSortOrder.Descending);
            #endregion

            workbook.SaveAs(filePath);
            ms.Close();
        }
    }
```

I went through several iterations of the below two expressions:

```
worksheet.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter().Column(salesFoundCell).EqualTo("Equipment Sale");
   worksheet.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter().Column(revenueFoundCell).EqualTo("00.00.0000");
```

I tried filtering directly on the columns, as a range, as a table, trying to hide the rows that did not have the required values.

All of it either filters based on one column or not at all.

The "expression.AddFilter(some value).AddFilter(some other value);" does not help as I am not trying to add multiple filters on the same column

The "And/Or" functionality does the same, multiple filters on the same column.

Has anyone managed to filter based on values in multiple columns?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is a misunderstanding of filters - you can only have one per sheet:see my question and self answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60325493/3561565

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sorting method found [here](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Sorting-Data)

```
myRange.SortColumns.Add(firstColumnNumber, XLSortOrder.Ascending);
myRange.SortColumns.Add(secondColumnNumber, XLSortOrder.Ascending);
myRange.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. I struggled with the same problem for a while.

The key is the sort, which has to be done after you define the filters.

```
var excelTable = TableRange.CreateTable();
excelTable.AutoFilter.Column(26).AddFilter("Filter 1");
excelTable.AutoFilter.Column(26).AddFilter("Filter 2");
excelTable.AutoFilter.Sort(1, XLSortOrder.Ascending);
```

Comment: Yes, this only works if you filter only one column.

This is what I am trying to do:

`var table = workbook.Worksheet(1).RangeUsed().CreateTable();
table.AutoFilter.Column(3).AddFilter("Filter 1");
table.AutoFilter.Column(58).AddFilter("Filter 2");
table.AutoFilter.Sort(1, XL.XLSortOrder.Ascending);`