# Applying multiple filters in ClosedXML (SetAutoFilter)

Tags: closedxml

I am applying filters for multiple columns via ClosedXML; however, only the last one is applied. Those filters work when they are alone. How can I apply all of them? I found similar question here 
[ClosedXML Excel filter rows by values in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324643/closedxml-excel-filter-rows-by-values-in-multiple-columns)

But there is no correct answer.

Here is the code:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook(loc1);
var ws2 = wb.AddWorksheet("Итоги");
var ws1 =  wb.Worksheet(1);
var rowCount = ws1.RowsUsed().Count();
ws1.Range(ws1.Cell(3,1), ws1.LastCellUsed()).SetAutoFilter().Column(48).EqualTo("1");
ws1.Range(ws1.Cell(3,1), ws1.LastCellUsed()).SetAutoFilter().Column(8).NotContains("CLS");
ws1.Range(ws1.Cell(3,1), ws1.LastCellUsed()).SetAutoFilter().Column(2).BeginsWith("I");
wb.SaveAs(loc1);
```

Here, only filter for Column 2 is applied, but I want all filters being applied. Is there a way to do so? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What version of ClosedXML?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct solution, but you can apply Multiple Excel formulas using IF(OR(condition1, condition2,...),0,1) and then use only filter to get 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

You can get an IXLAutoFilter reference and then use that for each filter you want to add.

```
IXLAutoFilter filter = ws1.Range(ws.Cell(3, 1), ws1.LastCellUsed()).SetAutoFilter(true);
filter.Column(48).EqualTo("1");
filter.Column(8).NotContains("CLS");
filter.Column(2).BeginsWith("I");
```

If an AutoFilter already exists in your table or range, then you can simply use that.

```
IXLAutoFilter filter = ws1.AutoFilter;
```