# How to set multiple filters in closedXML

Tags: closedxml

There are two unanswered questions out there on this:
[Applying multiple filters in ClosedXML (SetAutoFilter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095798/applying-multiple-filters-in-closedxml-setautofilter) and 
[ClosedXML Excel filter rows by values in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324643/closedxml-excel-filter-rows-by-values-in-multiple-columns)
This code will leave a single filter on the last range:

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("AutoFilter");
            ws.Cell("A1").Value = "Names";
            ws.Cell("A2").Value = "John";
            ws.Cell("A3").Value = "Hank";
            ws.Cell("A4").Value = "Dagny";

            var r1 = ws.Range("A1", "A4");
            r1.SetAutoFilter();

            ws.Cell("B1").Value = "Names";
            ws.Cell("B2").Value = "John";
            ws.Cell("B3").Value = "Hank";
            ws.Cell("B4").Value = "Dagny";
            var r2 = ws.Range("B1", "B4");
            r2.SetAutoFilter();

            wb.SaveAs(filterTest);
```

See the image: [only one filter in excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK8wu.jpg)

How can I add multiple filters?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding of filters here!
One filter per page is the rule, code below produces the desired result.

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("AutoFilter");
            ws.Cell("A1").Value = "Names";
            ws.Cell("A2").Value = "John";
            ws.Cell("A3").Value = "Hank";
            ws.Cell("A4").Value = "Dagny";


            ws.Cell("B1").Value = "id";
            ws.Cell("B2").Value = "1";
            ws.Cell("B3").Value = "2";
            ws.Cell("B4").Value = "3";
            var r2 = ws.Range("A1", "B4");
            r2.SetAutoFilter();

            wb.SaveAs(filtertest);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYmiz.jpg)